# How can I stop getting 2 different print results under same condition

Tags: python

newbie here. I want to get only one result when condition met but couldn't figure out how to do that.

```
            current_threshold = (max_bid_val - min_ask_val) * 100 / min_ask_val

        if (current_threshold > threshold) :

            alert_message = "Buy " + coin_list[i] + " on " + min_ask_place + " website for " + str(
                min_ask_val) + " price and Sell on " + max_bid_place + " for " + str(max_bid_val) + " price."
            alert_message_paribu = "Buy " + coin_list[i] + " on " + min_ask_place + " website for " + str((
                    min_ask_val * paribu_dic[symbol_usdt_tl][
                'highestBid'])) + " price and Sell on " + max_bid_place + " for " + str(max_bid_val) + " price."

            if 'paribu' in min_ask_place : 

                print(alert_message_paribu)
                start_alert(alert_message_paribu)
                telegram_send.send(messages=[alert_message_paribu])
                time.sleep(10)

            else :    #if min_ask_place is not paribu I need to get results as alert_message

                alert_message = "Buy " + coin_list[i] + " on " + min_ask_place + " website for " + str(
                min_ask_val) + " price and Sell on " + max_bid_place + " for " + str(max_bid_val) + " price."

            print(alert_message)
            start_alert(alert_message)
            telegram_send.send(messages=[alert_message])
            time.sleep(10)
```

any idea or suggestions? sorry if it's too ignorant. thanks

Comment: It prints twice because you ask it to. Move the other `print` inside the `else:` if you want it so either `alert_message_paribu` or `alert_message` is printed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two print statements where there is a condition that allows both to run. Does it print twice if 'paribu' is not in min_ask_place? maybe move the second print under the else.

Comment: Use comments to ask for clarifications. Answers must answer the question